# What is the difference between char *val and char *** val?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between char *val and char ***val. I know what pointers are but can not find anywhere what this triple star notation means.

Comment: One is a pointer to a `char`, one is an horrific mess.. :-)

Comment: _And what is char ****val and etc._:D

Answer (score 2):

Each star you add is another pointer, which means that `char *** val` is a pointer to another pointer that points to a `char` pointer

Answer (score 1):

The three stars/asterisks mean nothing special. Each of the stars indicate a level of indirection.

Let me exemplify:

`char *val` is a `char` pointer called val.

`char **val` is a pointer to a `char` pointer called val.

`char ***val` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char` pointer called val.

So an asterisk for each pointer level.

Comment: thank you. i would up vote but do not have the stupid reputation points yet.

Comment: @bluerubez If the _reputation points are stupid_, why do you want to _upvote_?

Comment: because i wish everything had a like button... that was free to use of course